# How do I add a custom mail header using the Office365 Preview API

Tags: api, preview, office365

I can't find anything in the preview API or the Microsoft.Office365.Exchange namespace to let me create a custom header or get the existing headers. Here's my code create the email and the recipients.

```
//Create the new Message with the Office365 API and save it to the Drafts folder
var client = await EnsureClientCreated();
var o365Message = new Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.Message();            
string subject = "Test subject";
o365Message.Subject = subject;
o365Message.Body = new ItemBody() { Content = "Test", ContentType = BodyType.Text };
messageModel.Subject = subject;
var recip = new Recipient();
recip.Address = "test@test.com";
o365Message.ToRecipients.Add(recip);
await client.Me.Drafts.Messages.AddMessageAsync(o365Message, false);
```

Thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't available right now from the service. I see nothing about mail headers in the [metadata](https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/$metadata) document. Please use [UserVoice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/) to request this feature.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I'll do the UserVoice request today.